# How to access free internet through a server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have an internet connection which is limited to only connect to some local servers in my area. In this area, I own a server which access is wider than my internet connection and through this server, I can SSH another server which is located in Finland. I use Ubuntu 19.10 on my personal laptop. Both these two servers are CentOS minimal.

Now my question is that how can I connect my local server to my other server in Finland to gain free internet access to every website, and how should I connect my laptop to my local server?

Now I have SSHed to my local server to see serverfault, but I cannot see other sites like twitter with this internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your contxt is wrong,You cannot access free internet via server. Change the question context and be clear in the question

Comment: This post does not belong here.  I would set up a couple of OpenVPN VPNs and route the traffic through them. An easier but more limited approach may be to use SSH forwarding  eg as per https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-set-up-a-two-hop-SOCKS5-proxy-over-ssh

Comment: @ManikandanRam as I know, someone else in my area is using this way and it's working for him, so in my idea it is correct. But I'll check the question and try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @davidgo has commented and [linked](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-set-up-a-two-hop-SOCKS5-proxy-over-ssh) this solution, it worked for me and now I have free access to everywhere.

Solution:
I ran this command on my terminal:

```
ssh -L 4699:127.0.0.1:4699 root@ip -pPort
```

And ran this command on my local server:

```
ssh -D 4699 root@finlandserver -pPort
```

And now as I google 'my ip', it shows me a Finnish IP.